# How to generate public interface of a Java class in Netbeans?

Tags: java, xcode, netbeans, interface

In XCode, there is a function where users can generate and see only the public interface of a class. I was just wondering if there is a similar function in NetBeans for Java classes.

Comment: Did you study the documentation?  It's probably called Extract Interface or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the class you want to extract the Source Editor / Project Window.
2. Choose Refactor -> Extract Interface.
3. Choose the methods you want to extract in the checkbox.
4. Success

I didn't listed steps like "click" next.